# Extract data from AJAX HTTP responseText

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Trying to get data from HTTP responseText

```
error: function(data) {
    $form.removeClass('is-uploading');
    $form.addClass('is-error');

    $errorMsg.text(data.responseText);
}
```

Getting

```json
{
    "message": "The given data was invalid.",
    "errors": {
        "files": [
            "The files must be a file of type: xls, xlsx."
        ]
    }
}
```

Tried using json.parse but errors not show

Comment: Do you want to display the error message?

Comment: Yes,want to display the errors -> files messages.

Comment: Then you can loop through `data.responseText.errors.files` and add each error to a `div` or `li`, whatever you like more.

Comment: But this shows ntg $errorMsg.text(data.responseText.errors.files);

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

```
$errorMsg.text(JSON.parse(data.responseText).errors.files);
```